# python socket always returns 'port closed', even though it is open

Tags: python, sockets, port

I am making a python program to scan the given host and ports from arguments.
If the socket connects to the port successfully it returns that the port is open, otherwise it returns closed. I checked those ports are all open (target is rapid7 metasploitable) using Nmap but the results always return closed.

[image: Scan result]

This is my python package directory structure.

```
ethical-hacking/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── scanning
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── connect_scan.py
        ├── get_target.py
        ├── port_scan.py
```

*** main.py

```
from scanning.port_scan import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port_scan()
```

*** get_target.py

```
import argparse
def get_target():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Usage of program: ' + '-H <target host> -p <target port>')
    parser.add_argument('-H', dest='targetHost', required=True, help='specify target host')
    parser.add_argument('-p', dest='targetPort', nargs='*', help='specify target ports separated by space')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    target_host = args.targetHost
    target_ports = args.targetPort
    if target_host is None or target_ports[0] is None:
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)
    return target_host, target_ports
```

*** connect_scan.py

```
import socket

def connect_scan(target_host, target_port):
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((target_host, target_port))
        print('[+] {}/tcp open'.format(target_port))
    except:
        print('[+] {}/tcp closed'.format(target_port))
    finally:
        sock.close()
```

*** port_scan.py

```
from socket import *
from threading import *

from .get_target import *
from .connect_scan import *

def port_scan():
    target = get_target()
    target_host = target[0]
    target_ports = target[1]

    try:
        target_ip = gethostbyname(target_host)
    except:
        print('Unknown host {}'.format(target_host))

    try:
        target_name = gethostbyaddr(target_ip)
        print('[+] Scan results for: ' + target_name[0])
    except:
        print('[+] Scan results for: ' + target_ip)

    for target_port in target_ports:
        t = Thread(target=connect_scan, args=(target_ip, target_port))
        t.start()
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to port numbers being strings rather than numbers. Your bare `except` clauses make it impossible to tell, as they throw away all information about what actually failed.

Comment: Thank you very very much, Jason. It works! When it comes to bare except, whenever I specified them, they keep causing another errors for some reason so I needed to remove them as a temporary measure. I know it is silly. I should go learn error handling case. Thanks, again.